# Why it is the length of my list different than the length of the same list cast to a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why it is showing True for list 1 if items in it are not same and False for second list if items it it are same. Please explain in details:

```
def test_distinct(data):
    if len(data) == len(set(data)):
        return True                              
    else:                                                                       
        return False
```

When I run:

```
print(test_distinct([1,5,7,9]))
```

I get:

```
True
```

When I run:

```
print(test_distinct([2,4,5,5,7,9]))
```

I get:

```
False
```

Please explain why == True if items in list are not similar and false when they are similar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The indentation is incorrect. Please [edit] to fix it. Please also explain what you're expecting exactly and why. Without context, I guess this is a function you got from somewhere else that tests if all elements in a collection are unique, which it seems to do properly.

Comment: `Set`'s can not have duplicates. So when the second list is converted to a set the two 5's become one. Therefore the length is different.

Comment: IndentationError - [edit] & fix please.

Comment: FWIW, the if-statement is redundant here. You can just `return len(data) == len(set(data))`

Comment: also: redundant code:   `def test_distinct(data): return len(data)==len(set(data))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So effectively the `set()` will parse (or convert if you will) your list (or tuple) into a new "set" which will contain only distinct iterable elements.

- In your first list: the len = 4 as is, and is 4 with any duplicates
  removed (which there are not in your first list).
- In your second list: the len = 6 as is, but len = 5 with the duplicate `5` removed (third and fourth items  in your second list) .

Comment: ok ok i got it thank you very much! wow thanx!

Comment: [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) is a type, not a method, and it doesn't "remove duplicates from the list" as much as it creates a new `set` out of the list, which skips duplicates. I'd edit your answer to clarify that myself but I'm not sure how to phrase it in a way that'd make sense for a newbie.

Comment: yes! thanks i've already under stood the concep for now! thanks a lot!

Comment: nums[i] == nums[i-1] ............please explain!